# Runtime error 1004 on ThisWorkbook.Activate

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

In the code below, it is failing at the "FORMAT TEMPLATE" comment. I get a run time error 1004. What I am doing is - I am closing the previous window (from copying the template) and pasting it into the good workbook. I don't think I am switching workbooks properly.

```
Sub BBUorders()
'OPEN TEMPLATE
Dim sPath As String, sFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook
sPath = "C:\Users\douglas.futato\Desktop\"
sFile = sPath & "BBU_CMD_TEMPLATE.xlsx"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)

'COPY TEMPLATE PASTE IN BBU DOC
Dim tmplt As Workbook
On Error Resume Next
    Set tmplt = Workbooks("BBU_CMD_TEMPLATE.xlsx")
    If tmplt Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Template file needs to be open..."
        Exit Sub
    End If
On Error GoTo 0
With ThisWorkbook
    tmplt.ActiveSheet.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
End With

'CLOSE TEMPLATE
Windows("BBU_CMD_TEMPLATE.xlsx").Activate
ActiveWindow.Close False

'FORMAT TEMPLATE --------- THIS IS WHERE IS BOMBS OUT
ThisWorkbook.Activate
Worksheets(“Sheet3”).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(-3, -8).Range("A1:H1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Cells.Replace What:="[BBU_CMD_TEMPLATE.xlsx]Price List", Replacement:=Sheet1.Name, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$61").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="0"
Rows("2:100").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=-18
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$18").AutoFilter Field:=6
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$18").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="0"
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$17").AutoFilter Field:=7
Range("E2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Range("E2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E50"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Range("E2:E21").Select
Range("I1").Select
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$50").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
Rows("8:100").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Range("A2:H2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$H$7").AutoFilter Field:=1
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: First thought would be...do you need that line at all?  If you only have 2 workbooks open, and you close one...there's only one left.  Secondly, cleaning that recorder code up with [Avoid Select/Activate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) will help make it much easier to read and follow.

Comment: I am new to VBA, I am learning - even removing "ThisWorkbook.Activate
Worksheets(“Sheet3”).Activate" it still produces the same error

Comment: The code isn't bombing on a comment. Is it the `ActiveWindow.Close` statement or the `ThisWorkbook.Activate` statement that's blowing up? In any case, your code relies way too much on `.Select` and `.Activate` to be anywhere near stable.

Comment: what you using 'ActiveCell.Offset(-3, -8).Range("A1:H1").Select' I guess "Range("A1:H1").Select" also work

Comment: `Worksheets(“Sheet3”).Activate` will crash because `“Sheet3”` is a completely different thing to `"Sheet3"` - `“Sheet3”` is a variable name - `"Sheet3"` is a string literal.  See the answer by Paul Co

Answer (score 1):

What I noticed is the `Worksheets(“Sheet3”).Activate`
Have you tried replacing it with `Worksheets("Sheet3").Activate`

The `ActiveCell.Offset` should not contain negative value.
e.g. If your active cell is (1, 1), you will get an error because
-3 - 1 is less than 1, and is not a valid row. (same with column)

Comment: Your first paragraph will be the answer to the problem - `“Sheet3”` is a variable name which won't have been assigned a value so will be `Empty`, and `Worksheets(Empty).Activate` isn't going to work.

Comment: Ah, the joys of copy+pasta programming! Nice catch!

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the cleanest code, but I figured out how to make it run. I had to add the worksheet as a reference. It was defaulting to sheet 2 when I was trying to work in the new sheet. Example: Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E45").Select

```
Sub templateToBBU()
'OPEN TEMPLATE
Dim sPath As String, sFile As String
Dim wb As Workbook
sPath = "C:\Users\douglas.futato\Desktop\"
sFile = sPath & "BBU_CMD_TEMPLATE.xlsx"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(sFile)

'COPY TEMPLATE PASTE IN BBU DOC
Dim tmplt As Workbook
On Error Resume Next
    Set tmplt = Workbooks("BBU_CMD_TEMPLATE.xlsx")
    If tmplt Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Template file needs to be open..."
        Exit Sub
    End If
On Error GoTo 0
With ThisWorkbook
    tmplt.ActiveSheet.Copy After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count)
End With

'CLOSE TEMPLATE
Windows("BBU_CMD_TEMPLATE.xlsx").Activate
ActiveWindow.Close False
End Sub
Sub Macro1()
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("A1:H1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Cells.Replace What:= _
    "C:\Users\douglas.futato\Desktop\[BBU_CMD_TEMPLATE.xlsx]Price List", _
    Replacement:=Sheet1.Name, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows,     
MatchCase _
    :=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("$A$1:$H$61").AutoFilter Field:=6, 
Criteria1:="0"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Rows("2:100").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("$A$1:$H$18").AutoFilter Field:=6
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("$A$1:$H$18").AutoFilter Field:=7, 
Criteria1:="0"
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("$A$1:$H$17").AutoFilter Field:=7
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E4").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E5").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E6").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E7").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E8").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E9").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E10").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E11").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E12").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E13").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E14").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E15").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E16").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E17").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E18").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E19").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E20").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E21").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E22").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E23").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E24").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E25").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E26").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E27").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E28").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E29").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E30").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E31").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E32").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E33").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E34").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E35").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E36").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E37").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E38").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E39").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E40").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E41").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E42").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E43").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E44").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E45").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E46").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E47").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E48").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E49").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E50").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("E51").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C+1"

'ST and Cust Mapping HERE
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("$A$1:$H$50").AutoFilter Field:=1, 
Criteria1:="="
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Rows("8:100").Select
Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
Worksheets("TEMPLATE").Range("$A$1:$H$50").AutoFilter Field:=1


End Sub

Sub Main()
Call templateToBBU
Call Macro1
End Sub
```

Comment: Ok. Now read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) and stop writing macro-recorder code.